# Working with a JavaScript for a onclick event

Tags: javascript

so I'm creating an onclick event in JavaScript but I'm having some issues with uncaught type error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows') I have been trying to fix this for a while now and would like some input or suggestions.

```
if (obj.parentElement.rowIndex!=0) {
    sTable=obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id
    objinitable = eval("document.all.ini" + sTable.substr(3))
    objrectable = eval("document.all.rec" + sTable.substr(3))

    sParameters = objinitable.rows(0).cells(obj.cellIndex).innerText
    aParameters =sParameters.split("/")
    sfunction=aParameters[4]
```

Comment: `objinitable` is `undefined`

Comment: What is this line doing? `eval("document.all.ini" + sTable.substr(3))`. For me it returns `undefined`. Javascript then tries to access this `objinitable.read` property but it doesn't exist (the whole `objinitable` is "unexisting"). This is why you get the error. Explain in the question what you want to achieve. Also `obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id` seems like a bad practice.

Comment: @deaponn error doesn't say anything about `rows` being `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but I think you're using `eval()` wrong. `eval()` returns the result of an operation, not an object. I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
if (obj.parentElement.rowIndex != 0) {
    sTable=obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id
    objinitable = document.all["ini" + sTable.substr(3)]
    objrectable = document.all["document.all.rec" + sTable.substr(3)]

    sParameters = objinitable.rows(0).cells(obj.cellIndex).innerText
    aParameters =sParameters.split("/")
    sfunction = aParameters[4]
```

Comment: Better practice to use `querySelector` than the ancient DOM Level 0 `document.all`, especially nested...